# Comparing TN vs. IPS LCD monitors for gaming

Tags: pc, performance, monitor

Having never owned an LCD desktop monitor, I'm wondering what the advantages and disadvantages are between owning a [TN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_nematic) and an [IPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPS_panel) monitor in regards to gaming performance. While I know there are several factors upon which you can compare the two for general usage, I'm primarily concerned with the differences in gaming experience between them and what factors I would need to consider when comparing the two.

I'm currently having difficulty disseminating information from pages and pages of forum posts. What I'm primarily looking for is a comparison between the following points, though any additional information in regards to differing factors would also be welcome:

- Refresh rate
- Responsiveness
- Graphics/texture quality differences due to varying color depth in displays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some considerations about IPS vs TN competition:

- IPS **costs more** than TN
- IPS **reproduce colors better** than TN
- IPS has a **wider viewing angle** than TN
- IPS has a **slower response time** (latency) than TN monitors (5-8 ms vs 2-5 ms)
- IPS (at the moment) **does not support a 120 Hz refresh rate**. Therefore if you want to play 3D games (e.g. using NVidia 3D Vision) on IPS monitor you can have 30 fps maximum (60/2).

These are general assumptions about these two different monitor technologies. Then every product has his own story. You can read some good reviews on websites like, for example, [Digital Versus](http://www.digitalversus.com/monitors-article-923.html#currentmonitor).

Said this, if you do not plan to watch many movies or to play a lot of FPS/action games and you have the budget I suggest you a good IPS monitor because their are wonderful to work with (program, web design, etc.). Otherwise, go for a good TN monitor.

Comment: Accepting this as an answer because of the great link to Digital Versus. While my question is a bit general in scope, that site has proved immensely helpful in supplementing other questions I had about more specific properties.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, TN displays have faster response times but IPS technology has been rapidly improving in that aspect.  However, TN is still much cheaper than IPS.

IPS does offers a richer color and wider viewing angle, great for more general purpose use such as multimedia.

[This article](http://www.pchardwarehelp.com/guides/lcd-panel-types.php) is a good read about the pros and cons of each.

@FallenAngelEyes sorry if it wasn't much help.  The only important piece of advise I'd offer is to go with the IPS monitor, yes you pay a little more, but in the future, should you choose to add a second monitor (when IPS is cheaper), you don't want to be stuck with a TN + IPS monitor since the contrast can be big enough to induce headaches (at least for me).  I have a IPS+TN setup and I regret it immensely.

Comment: While I agree the link is informative, it didn't really give me any more detail on the criteria I was looking for before I came here. The vagueness on what constitutes "fast paced games" and the lack of hard numbers aside from the brief mention of average response time is somewhat disappointing.

Comment: I missed your response because you edited into your answer, sorry about that! In the future, I'll get the @ notification if you add it as a comment rather than editing. :)

Comment: The future is here, and IPS is still not cheaper than TN ^^.

Answer (score 1):

I read a [decent article](http://gaming-monitors.com/definitive-ips-guide/) that covered all these issues.

The short rundown is = IPS (inplane switching), its pixels are organized in a different way to TN (Twisted nematic). TN, generally, has faster hertz and response times, its also cheaper, currently, to manufacture. TN are a kind of cheap and nasty solution to fast hertz and ms.

IPS has superior colors and viewing angles, its a bit more expensive, but quickly catching up to TN in speed.

Answer (score 0):

IPS is better than TN in terms of clarity, wide viewing angle, but costly.

Those are the main differences. IPS screens generally have a response time of around 8ms, sometimes 5 depending on the model. TN screens generally have 2ms - 5ms sometimes 8ms. So no big difference there.

Refresh rate will be 59Hz or 60Hz just like every normal monitor.

Colors are displayed better on an IPS then a TN. People say the colors on a IPS have more depth and are more pure then those on an TN.

That's everything I know/found about IPS vs TN I hope it'll help you :)